# Adding the contents of an intArray

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I'm trying to sum the contents of an integer array using a for loop. Logically I'm stuck. Here is my code:

```
<p id='para'></p>

var someArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

function sum () {

  for(i=0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
      return someArray += someArray[i];
  }
}

document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = sum();
```

The answer should obviously be 15 but how do I get there? Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: You're returning too early

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your return statement is too early. It's causing you to return on the first time it runs through the for loop. `return` pulls you out of the loop.

```
<p id='para'></p>

var someArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

function sum () {

  var returnValue = 0;

  for(i=0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
      returnValue += someArray[i];
  }
  return returnValue;
}

document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = sum();
```

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of mistakes in your sum function, first of all you don't need return statement inside for loop, instead of that you could use any temp variable to store summation of array elements and return that temp variable.

```
function sum () {
  var total=0;
   for(i=0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
     total += someArray[i];
  }
  return total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily achieved by using `reduce()` like below:

```js
var someArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

var res = someArray.reduce(function(all, item, index){
  return all+item
},0);

document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = res;
```

```html
<p id='para'></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Return statement place with wrong ..add the return in after for loop .Declare the one variable to before for loop and then add with array values in this variable.

```js
function sum () {
var a=0;
  for(i=0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
    a += someArray[i];
  }
  return a
}
console.log(sum());
```

or simply use `Array#reduce`

```js
var someArray = [1,2,3,4,5].reduce((a,b) => {return a+b})

console.log(someArray)
```